# Rest Service Get operation issue

Tags: rest, tomcat7

I am calling a Rest Service in a war file deployed on my local Apache Tomcat server using a Get request and the URL" "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users returns a user but the URL "http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users/1" returns a HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error - i am new to REST services and could not figure why that is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Not found error" is because you don't have any api listening to /users/1. Why are you sending the /1 ?

Comment: i was trying to retrieve just a single resource as opposed to multiple ones

Comment: And is there a user with ID = 1?

Comment: yes - it comes back in the response from a Get request when i use this URL - ""http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users"